# MySQL query (with JOIN) only retrieving the first row

Tags: php, mysql, join

Here is my query

```
$getPosts = mysql_query ('SELECT `posts`.*, COUNT(`comments`.`comment_id`) 
                          FROM `posts` 
                          LEFT JOIN `comments` 
                          ON (`posts`.`post_id` = `comments`.`post_id`) 
                          ORDER BY `posts`.`post_id` DESC')
            or die(mysql_error());
```

and then to loop through it...

```
while ($post = mysql_fetch_row($getPosts))
{
    echo $post[1] . ' ' . $post[4] . ' comments'; // example
}
```

it all works fine, but only for the first row.

now, post_id 1 has 2 comments. post_id 2 has no comments in the DB.

I assume this is how JOIN works, but I don't understand. I think LEFT JOIN only matches what's on the left (so post_id) but I tried INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, etc.. and it doesn't work

Comment: update: I tried FULL JOIN (after checking w3schools again), and it says "Unknown table 'posts'"

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: noted and amended. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `COUNT()` aggregate must be used with a `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL will return results without it, but they won't be the result you expect, as it will return one related row, indeterminately.

```
SELECT
  `posts`.*, 
  `c`.`num_comments`
FROM
  `posts` 
  /* join against a subquery which retrieves the number of comments per post_id */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `post_id`, COUNT(*) AS `num_comments` 
    FROM `comments`
    GROUP BY `post_id` 
  ) AS c ON (`posts`.`post_id` = `c`.`post_id`) 
ORDER BY
  `posts`.`post_id` DESC
```

MySQL will probably allow you to simplify this without the subquery, since it won't require every column from `posts` to be listed in the `GROUP BY`, but this isn't recommended as it won't work everywhere.

```
/* MySQL only, not recommended */
SELECT
  posts.*,
  COUNT(comments.comment_id) AS num_comments
FROM 
  posts
  LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

Otherwise, you will need to list every column from `posts` in the `GROUP BY` since they are all the `SELECT`. This will work because the join involves only the one to many relationship `posts` to `comments`.

When you fetch this row in PHP, use the alias `num_comments`. It is recommended to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), and access columns by their name rather than a numeric key.

```
while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts))
{
    echo $post['post_id'] . ' ' . $post['num_comments'] . ' comments';
}
```

In the long run, as noted in the comments above, consider switching to a newer API such as MySQLi or PDO, as the `mysql_*()` extension is facing deprecation in the next major PHP verison.

Comment: worked perfect. thanks. is there any way to do this without aliases though (just curious as I'm still learning about formatting queries). thanks

Comment: @cantsay you don't need to alias the table `comments`, I just did it as `c` to save typing.  You can skip the alias on the `COUNT()` too, but then you have to specify it the same way in the array key when you fetch it.  It is far more readable to use the alias.